# Bundler not recognizing local gem path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

For a site on its current server, running `bundle install --path vendor/bundle --full-index` runs with no issues. However, when I run this for the same site on my new server (same version of Bundler), I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
An error occurred while installing userstamp (2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install userstamp -v '2.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

That specific gem is defined like this in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'userstamp', '2.0.2', path: "vendor/local_gems/userstamp"
```

and the gem is present there. This means that Bundler is ignoring the `path` option in the Gemfile. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Try forcing the rubygems version to be same in both systems. gem update --system version_from_working _system

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  gem update --system version_from_working_system
```